# UploadFile big size inYii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2

When I try to upload a file more than about 100MB by `yii\web\UploadedFile` the file isn't uploaded. But all fields become empty and each field has the validation error:

> field cannot be blank

This is my validation rules:

```
   public function rules() {
    return [
        [['name_promo_file', 'description_promo_file', 'url_promo_file', 'size_promo_file', 'lang_promo_file'], 'required'],
        [['date_upload_promo_file'], 'safe'],
        [['size_promo_file'], 'integer'],
        [['lang_promo_file'], 'string'],
        [['name_promo_file', 'description_promo_file', 'url_promo_file'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['imagePromo'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'pdf doc png, jpg, jpeg']
    ];
}`
```

This is my php.ini setting

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M  
post_max_size = 256M
max_execution_time = 60
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: by default 2 MB will be easily uploaded. I have tried uploading 100MB but no luck with yii2 syntax, max to max, I was able to upload 15mb, more than 15mb cause connection failed on the server. I suggest with go with Jquery Drag and Drop, works great. gives you file upload progress and all.

Comment: I've tested it with up to 200MB, nothing is wrong, just increase max_sizes in php config. Not sure what is happening about your problem, but I believe that something is wrong with the code itself (in your controller or model)

Comment: @Yerke can you share your code, I m interested in using it.

Comment: try to improve max_execution_time, 60 seconds can be not enought for upload big file in your server

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but i solved by using kartiks file input widget and increasing the size in php.ini ,Here you please seperate the extensions as pdf,docx,....please do a reply if the problem is not solved.hope we can solve it.